# Inserted SWF file loads and after a few secons turns white and unresponsive

Tags: hosting, flash, dreamweaver, flash-cs6

I have created a simple working gallery in Flash CS6 with AS3 and published it in SWF.
Then I've inserted it with Dreamweaver into a empty HTML file and uploaded it to my host.
**The problem** is that it loads and works but goes white after a few seconds, when i right click it, it reacts like a regular flash.
Refreshing doesn't help it stays white and doesn't even work for those few seconds after the first load.
My host is Hostinger Polska. I will provide any information if needed.

EDIT
I've just found out with the help of the chrome dev tools that my SWF is canceled when loading the site but still i have no idea why.
http://spektrum.edu.pl/test/Untitled-1.html

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the question? Maybe share a link to your published site? This question gives very little information, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your swif file works fine but the way you embed it is wrong.
Remove all that dirty html and follow the manual here:
https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: It seems that dreamweaver has generated some dirty HTML and it works now thanks to mika. Thank you.